React Leaflet "Draw a Marker" option doesnt show marker icon
Using  component with the custom icon works anyway, but trying to mark the location using the tool in the right side doesn't show the marker image.
Thanks in advance.
const MarkerIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: '/images/locationMarker.svg',
  iconSize: [40, 40],
});
L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = MarkerIcon;

L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
   iconRetinaUrl: require('../images/locationMarker.svg'),
   iconUrl: require('../images/locationMarker.svg'),
   shadowUrl: require('../images/locationMarker.svg'),
});

L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
   iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
   iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
   shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png'),
});

All the above snippets didn't work.

